# rosserial_arduino IDE error

Tags: arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install `ros_lib` into the arduino environment. When I try compile `HellowWorld`, I have error:

```
 In file included from /home/tuuzdu/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h:38:0,
                     from /home/tuuzdu/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/ros.h:38,
                     from HelloWorld.pde:6:
    /opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/Time.h:42:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

File `/opt/ros/hydro/include/std_msgs/Time.h` exists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183235/rosserial_arduino-ide-error/) by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-07-05**:
Did your rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py call run without errors/warnings? Does Time.h exist somewhere in a subfolder of your /home/tuuzdu/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib/?

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2014-07-06**:
I have this problem on 64bit machine and I have not problem on 32bit machine. Both machines with Ubuntu 13.04 and ROS Hydro. On 32bit make_libraries.py creates headers in ros_lib folder: std_msgs, rosserial_msgs and others.But on 64bit not! I try copy header primary-to-secondary, but it hasnt effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps ROS is not in the path of the utility you are using... But the error seems to be pointing to the following segment of Time.h:

```
#ifndef STD_MSGS_MESSAGE_TIME_H
#define STD_MSGS_MESSAGE_TIME_H


#include <string> //This line here is line 42
#include <vector>
#include <map>

#include <ros/types.h>
#include <ros/serialization.h>
#include <ros/builtin_message_traits.h>
#include <ros/message_operations.h>
```

So I'd say it's got to do with rosserial's PATH. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on this... I've used it only slightly. If you are launching from the system, try launching from a terminal. Perhaps this is like the issue with QtCreator... You can only use it in a terminal in order to get the right paths linked. Please note that this is simply speculation, though...

Keep us posted! This could definitely be helpful for others in the future.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuuzdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8026/tuuzdu/) on 2014-07-06**:
Yes, I launch Arduino IDE from terminal with all necessary environment variables. Please see comment above.

**Comment by [fyi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41025/fyi/) on 2020-12-28**:
did you get a solution to this?